# Store The Content Of The Selected Line Of a TListBox On a Variable

Tags: delphi, list, listview, variables, lazarus

I'm developing a ebook manager on Lazarus, but I'm having some troubles with a component that I've never used(`TListBox`). On the `TListBox` named `CategoryList`, I have these items:

> Literature and Fiction
>   Romance
>   Computers and Internet
>   Poetry
>   Professional and Technical
>   Science Fiction and Fantasy
>   Biographies and Memoirs
>   Business and Finance
>   Children's Books
>   Entertainment
>   History
>   Science
>   Self-Help
>   Textbooks and Educational Materials
>   Travel
>   Westerns

When the user select an item on the `CategoryList`, I want to store it in a variable, but how can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the index:

```
index := CategoryList.ItemIndex;
```

If you want the string:

```
str := CategoryList.Items[CategoryList.ItemIndex];
```

To capture the moment the user selects something, you need to register an OnChange event:

```
CategoryList.OnChange := CategoryListChange;
```

Where the CategoryListChange is an event listener:

```
procedure TMyForm.CategoryListChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // do something with CategoryList.Items[CategoryList.ItemIndex]
end;
```

You might want to look on some of the posts on [this webpage](http://delphi.about.com/od/tlistbox/TListBox_Delphi_Usage_Examples_Tips_and_Tricks.htm) too!

Comment: +1 and test `if(CategoryList.ItemIndex > -1)` before using it as index for Items property.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help and for the link, that is very useful to learn. I'm going to make some exercises of TListBox to be better.